# How to use sub.find function

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble getting my code to work. To summarize the user enters a first, middle and last name. The program will then print the names initials, but I don't know how to display the last name initial. I know I have to make it so it activates after the first space, but I don't know how to do that.
Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string name="";
   int finder=0;
   int lastfinder=0;

   cout << "Enter a first name, middle and last name" << endl;
    getline(cin,name); // gets user input

   finder = name.find(" ",0); //finds the middle name initial
   lastfinder = name.find(" ");  //finds the last name initial
   //uses .find to find a specific string in another

   if(finder>=0)cout << "The initials are: " <<name.substr(0,1)<<name.substr(finder,2)<<name.substr(lastfinder,2)<<endl;
    //displays information to user

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lastfinder = name.find(" ", finder+1);  //finds the last name initial
```

By adding `finder+1` to line above, `find` method starts searching from next character after first space character. Without it, `name.find(" ", 0)` and `name.find(" ")` are basically same since second argument's default value is 0 in method's declaration in string class definition:

```
size_t find (const char* s, size_t pos = 0) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have written a very basic and simple code for this if you are sure that user will enter three name.

```cpp
string fname,mname,lname;
cin>>fname>>mname>>lname;
cout<<fname[0]<<mname[0]<<lname[0];
```

This input will be space separated hence each name will be in its respective variable and then you display them.

Your code is fine, you only need to add a starting index for last name i.e. it should be:

```cpp
lastfinder = name.find(" ",finder+1);
```

`+1` is important as you need to start after the space; not right on it, which will again give you the same space on which you already are.

A better code would be this:

```cpp
    string name;
    int m_ind = -1;
    int l_ind = -1;
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<name[0];
    m_ind=name.find(" ");
    if (m_ind == -1) return 0;
        cout<<name[m_ind+1];
    l_ind = name.find(" ",m_ind+1);
    if(l_ind == -1) return 0;
    cout<<name[l_ind+1];
```